# My cafe roma machine doesn't provide enough pressure to push water through the finest setting of my grinder

Tags: espresso-machine, maintenance

I've had to turn the setting down on my grinder, but I know the espresso isn't as good. It's not as rich.

When i put it on the highest setting, the espresso drips out, one drip a second, and that tastes like proper espresso, but its way too slow and I'm worried the machine is going to break.

Is there a way to try and fix the machine? Is it possible my machine is simply too cheap to make proper espresso? (FYI I recently decalcified the machine and that didn't help much.)

Comment: It has enough pressure. You should just not grind on the finest setting. If there's no water pumping through, that is just what it means. Maybe specify how you try to make the espresso and then we can help you figure out a nice recipe.

Comment: Also do you have the possibility to weigh out the ground coffee and the finale espresso? You should use (for double shot in the double basket) around 18-20g of grounds and get 36-40g of ready espresso at around 25s (that's just an average and depending on the coffee you might just need 20s or 30s). Which coffee do you use (origin, roast level, brand etc.)?